# java stream filter vs if-else condition, which one is faster?

Tags: java, if-statement, filter, java-stream

Recently I started using JAVA-8 features, while implementing I have used stream filters. for my requirement I am filtering first and then updating in another loop. so I have iterated my loop twice. while in older way I could do the filtering and update on the same loop. So which one is better java stream filter & update or old way if-else and update?

## sample code

```
private static void updateRank(List<DataDTO> dataList, Flag flag) {
    int rank = 1;
    List<DataDTO> updatedList = dataList.stream().filter(d -> flag.equals(d.getFlag())).sorted(Comparator.comparing(DataDTO::getUsdAmout).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    for (DataDTO data : updatedList) {
        data.setRank(data.getFlag().getTypeDesc() + " Rank " + rank++);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first operation, you are sorting the content as well which means there is a further runtime complexity added.

Comment: You can also do the same in the stream, before collect you can do .peek and inside the peek lambda setRank in your items.

Nevertheless it should not differ much, it does not change the O complexity

Comment: There is no clean way to access the "loop index" in a stream. You may as well stick to your original for loop. In Kotlin there is a `forEachIndexed` method that would enable you to do it cleanly.

Comment: **Beware of premature optimization** Base your selection of syntactical options on *readbility*. Do not prefer one option over another for performance reasons unless you have *proven my measurement* that the code in question really is the bottleneck *and* the alternative really solves the performance issue.

Comment: I don’t see, how you could do this with only one loop. So, unless you show how your “older way” is supposed to solve his task, the question makes no sense. For a comparison, you need at least two things.